# How to replace fragment on default blank activity (with fragment)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

I've got 4 files in my layout (the 3 auto-generated and my fragment) :

activity_main.xml

content_main.xml

fragment_main.xml

my_custom_fragment.xml

I've made a new class that holds my fragment.

On my main fragment I've made an event that call this in order to replace 
the fragment.

`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .replace(R.id.fragment, new CustomFragment())
                        .commit();`

Then it only adds my layout to the current one instead of replacing it ...

Comment: can you post you code clearly in how you created CustomFragment. and also tell what you want from it?

Comment: The code to create my custom fragment is just in main thread (called when I click on a button).
I want it to replace the fragment (as for now it adds it below to the previous layout displayed on the screen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment that you are trying to replace was created through a `<fragment>` in XML. Such a fragment cannot be removed or added dynamically.

Comment: Yes I just realized that was the problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your previous fragment first something like

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .remove(previousFragmentObject).commit();
```

and then add new fragment.